# QGIS Keeps removing itself from my MacBook

Tags: qgis, mac

I am new to QGIS and the details of how the program works. I have a MacBook Pro with the latest operating system. I downloaded QGIS fine and have used the program with no issues while using the program.

My issue is it seems to 'remove' itself from my computer, it has happened 3 times so far. All of a sudden, the icon on the desktop and any sign of it or the 'disk' are gone from my computer randomly. The .dmg file remains in my downloads folder and I can reinstall it again and find my work fine, but I have no idea what's doing on.

Comment: Caveat... I don't use a Mac anymore, and have never used one with QGIS... But are you actually installing the software - i.e mounting the DMG disk image and dragging to Applications, or running an installer (if the QGIS DMG includes one), or just mounting the DMG and running from that?

Comment: ahh forgive my ignorance, I am new to QGIS but also new to using a Mac. I have always just downloaded and installed a program and it's good to go. I don't exactly understand the difference between running off the installer vs 'mounting the dmg disk', but I dragged QGIS into Applications and it appears there now so I think that may have been my problem. Thank you for taking the time to answer my question!

Comment: Think of the DMG as a disk drive (e.g CD/DVD, USB).  It gets mounted (inserted, plugged in) when you open the DMG and unmounted (ejected, unplugged) when you restart your computer. Afterwards, you still have the disk drive but it's not connected to your computer. You actually need to copy the software (install it) from the drive to your computer to make it permanent.